# Best way to seal a funky gap on shower door frame

Tags: shower, waterproofing, caulking, spray-foam, seal

I am trying to fix a gap at the shower door frame which I think resutled from previous owner's improper installation/sealing.

As you can see, there is this little gap at the shower door frame. That orange stick was from the hole, part of the unsuccessful sealing attempt from the previous owner, I believe.

The gap is in a very hard to access spot and direct sealing would't fully fill it up. I am wondering if I could apply some waterproof sealing foams on it?

Would these products be the right one I am looking for? Are they waterproof enough to apply on shower door gaps, or it's just general waterproof that can't really be used in shower door frame.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Loctite-12-fl-oz-Tite-Foam-Insulating-Foam-2045981/206310510

http://www.premierbuildingsolutions.net/product/xtrafoam-minimal-expanding-foam-sealant/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Gap doesn't look that big. I would use silicone caulk.